# Which alternative SQL queries can I use to count non-empty rows in a table?

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

I want to know if there is a risk of double counting customer-Ids that are with and without spacing. What I expect is if spacing is introduced on Ids, there is a possibility of double counting the same Ids.

I used the following query to count the number of customers buying movies

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) As count_all
FROM 
    movies
WHERE 
    customer_id is not NULL;
```

Comment: Your question is much too vague. Please show both sample data and the expected result as tables, explain what exactly you want to do and what exactly is your question.

Comment: `TRIM()` removes leading and trailing spaces... in most RDBMS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

IDs in a table should not have leading or trailing spaces. You must make sure that your data is being stored correctly. I don't know your table and database structure, but is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) As count_all
FROM 
    movies
WHERE 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(customer_id,''))) <> ''
```

If you are using SQL 2017 and up you can replace the
`RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(customer_id,''))) <> ''` with `TRIM(ISNULL(customer_id,'')) <> ''`